# How to stack promises dynamically?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have a nested object `subprojects` with a property of type array: `userEstimates` holding object(s) `Estimate`.

I am looking to iterate through `userEstimates` and push a fetch/promise to an array without calling it.

main (inside `async` function)

```
await subproject.getUserEstimates(true);
let stack = [];

subproject.userEstimates.forEach(ue =>
    stack.push(ue.fetchAvailableRates)
);

console.log(stack);  // 3) [ƒ, ƒ, ƒ]

await Promise.all(stack);

fillForm(subproject);
```

however, attributes on `subproject` are not defined when calling `fillForm`

function definition for `fetchAvailableRates`:

```
fetchAvailableRates = () => {
  this.availableRates = fetch(...)
  .then((resp) => {
    if (resp.ok) return resp.json();
    else throw new Error("Something went wrong");
  })
  .then((r) => {
    ...

    return {
      Rate.get(), // returns class
      ...
    };
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
};
```

EDIT: Changed my wording frrom queue to stack as i'm trying to run all requests at once, and I don't care about order

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're trying to do. `Promise.all()` accepts Promises, not functions, but if you call `fetchAvailableRates` and fill the stack with Promises then `Promise.all()` will work and return an array of rates (though there's no code you've shown us that puts those returned rates back into the subproject). Can you help us understand why "without calling it" is important and what you want to have happen?

Comment: @JeffBowman you helped lead me to it, my `fetchAvailableRates()` wasn't returning the promise

Comment: Oh, I see what was going on. I'll answer, but you can also self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition for `fetchAvailableRates` uses `this`, but when you refer to an object's function without calling it (like `stack.push(ue.fetchAvailableRates)`), it loses the reference to `this` and simply becomes a function.

To refer to a function that calls `ue.fetchAvailableRates` on the `ue` instance at the time, you should call either `() => ue.fetchAvailableRates()` or `ue.fetchAvailableRates.bind(ue)`.

That's not the only change you'd need to make―`Promise.all()` doesn't accept functions, only promises, so the right call is probably to make `ue.fetchAvailableRates()` return the Promise and add that to the stack.